# PHP Regex - Minimum of 8 characters, 1 letter, 1 number

Tags: php, regex

So I thought I had this right?

```
        if(!preg_match('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+.{7,}$', $passOne)) {
            $msg = "Password does not contain at least 1 number/letter, 8 character minimum requirement.";
        }
```

I test it over at https://regex101.com/ and put `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+.{7,}$` to work and things like `RubyGlue12` pass and is a match and other things that aren't.

But no matter what, I cannot make any match in the actual PHP code. Even if the POST is a variable manually.

edit: `$_POST['password']` is `$passOne`

Help?

Comment: You forot to place delimiters around your regex pattern: `preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+.{7,}$/', $passOne)...`

Comment: You really shouldn't [limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: Use: `if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/', $passOne)) ...`

Comment: @anubhava Let's bet when the first answers will copy the delimiters mentioned here...

Comment: Are you sure that there must be just 1 letter? Not 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase letters?

Comment: @JayBlanchard My employer :(

Comment: Drat @GaoLin, my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `.+.{7,}` that does not make much sense since it means *match any characters 1 or more times, and then any characters 7 or more times*.

1 letter, 1 digit and min 8 characters regex will look like

```
(?i)^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?i)` - Turning case sensitivity off (**unless you need to check for 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letters** - then, remove the `i` flag and replace `(?=.*[a-z])` with `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])`)
- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Positive look-ahead requirement to have at least 1 letter
- `(?=.*\d)` - Positive look-ahead requirement to have at least 1 digit
- `.{8,}` - At least 8 characters
- `$` - End of string.

And PHP code is:

```
$re = "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).{8,}$/i"; 
$passOne = "RubyGlue12";
//$passOne = "eee"; // uncomment to echo the error message
if(!preg_match($re, $passOne)) {
  echo "Password does not contain at least 1 number/letter, 8 character minimum requirement.";
}
```

And yes, with `preg_match` function, you must use some regex delimiters. I am using `/` here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that tests for what the password **should not** be, instead of what it **should** be.

```
/^(.{0,7}|[^a-z]*|[^\d]*)$/i
```

**Example:**

```
if (preg_match('/^(.{0,7}|[^a-z]*|[^\d]*)$/i', $passOne)) {
  echo "Validation failed.\n";
}
```

**Explanation:**

There are essentially 3 separate tests within the regex (each separated by a `|`, and each are case-insensitive due to the `i` option at the end). If it *passes* any of the tests, then the entire validation *fails*.

- **Test 1:** Does the entire string only contain 0-7 characters? **Fail.**
- **Test 2:** Does the entire string contain no alpha characters? **Fail.**
- **Test 3:** Does the entire string contain no digits? **Fail.**